# Java Regex to get JSON schema

Tags: java, regex, json

I need to get a JSON object from a String

in this string the JSON content is unique with this form:

abit2:{....};

I made my regex this way, but I'm unable to stop at semicolon

```
public String getJSON(String content) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

    String json = "";       

    String regex = "abit2:([\\s\\S]*)\\};"; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);     
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        json = matcher.group().replace("abit2:", "");       
    }

    return json;        
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. There are some well known JSON parser libraries in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to include the opening curly brace  and you need to make this `[\\s\\S]*` pattern as non-greedy.

```
String regex = "abit2:\\{([\\s\\S]*?)\\};";
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jP8dE4/5)